# iTerm2 save window/tabs on exit?

Tags: macos, iterm

I tried to save a window arrangement but when I open iTerm it opens two windows:

1. one with my saved arrangement
2. one with no arrangements

How can I make iTerm2 remember my Window/tabs layout?

Answer (score 6):

This was answered on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/726338/how-to-automatically-restore-window-arrangement-from-last-time-in-iterm) by another user and the solution worked for me.

Turn off prefs>general>open default window arrangement, and turn off system prefs>general>close windows when quitting an application.

Comment: awesome!! thank you for the TL;DR!!

Answer (score 0):

First create some profiles and then use Command - Option/Alt - Shift H (H is for horizontal split; or swap in V for vertical split). It will show you a list of your profiles and you can then add those to your split. This short video shows how: [iterm2 Profiles and Window Arrangements](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOrwEYu_QiY).

Comment: Thanks for the Video I learnt some new tricks. But my problem is when I quit iTerm2 & open it back. it doesn't save the last state it was on, even with window arrangements.